# Laptop monitor brightness changes according to the image displayed

Tags: windows, laptop, drivers, display, brightness

I have a windows 10 laptop. My desktop background is very dark (almost black) and when i have no windows open, my brightness dims. When i open an application that is primarily white (google chrome's start page) or just a white image, the screen brightens. It seems to be caused by the color of the image displayed on the screen.
I have most likely ruled out "Adaptive Brightness" because I do not have an ambient light sensor